# Finite topologies --- what are they good for?

Tags: general-topology

Do finite topologies have any practical uses other than for counterexamples

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/177461/how-much-of-homotopy-theory-can-be-done-using-only-finite-topological-spaces

Comment: FINITE TOPOLOGIES! HUH (yeah)! What are they good for? ABSOLUTELY NOTHING! (Say it again!)

Comment: @Asaf A one syllable word to a six syllable phrase? That won't do at all!

Comment: These answers [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837319/what-application-is-there-for-a-non-hausdorff-topological-space/837416#837416) [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456309/why-are-topological-spaces-interesting-to-study/456418#456418) discuss an important application of the Sierpiński space, which is a topological space with two points.  (It is the unique topological space with two points that is neither the discrete nor the indiscrete space.)

Comment: Edwin Starr, 1969: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01-2pNCZiNk  "Originally written under the Motown label, and first performed by The Temptations, "War" was later re-released as a single with Edwin Starr as vocals. This version is considered a more emotional version and has become the most popular protest song ever." He is better than I remembered

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if the question we should really be asking is 'Do we really need infinite topological space [when finite space seem to be good enough](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077376525)?'

Comment: @daniel Infinite topological spaces are models of intuitionistic logic.  Finite spaces never are.

Comment: @MJD Sorry I was being a little tongue-in-cheek. I don't seriously consider finite spaces enough to cover everything we do with infinite spaces, but I think the link I gave highlights just how much homotopy theory we can actually do with just finite spaces.

Comment: I think this could be a good question if phrased as a reference request.

Comment: @AustinMohr You can still give answers supported by references, whether or not references are explicitly asked for...

Answer (score 1):

For instance the Sierpinski space $(S, \tau)$ with $S = \{0,1\}$ and $\tau = \{\emptyset, \{0\}, S\}$ is quite useful, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space . Also, with this kind of "minimal sandbox" topology you can learn about closures, continuous maps, and so on without having to deal with infinite sets.